# FIFO implementation in C

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, esp8266, fifo

I am analysing an Internet guide, where I fond code like that. Can somebody explain me the usage of ~ and & operators?

Thanks in advance

```
uint8_t tx_fifo_put(tx_dataType data)
{
/*Check if FIFO is full*/
    if((tx_put_itr - tx_get_itr) & ~(TXFIFOSIZE-1))
        {
            /*FIFO full - return TXFAIL*/
            return (TXFAIL);
        }

    /*Put data into fifo*/
    TX_FIFO[tx_put_itr & (TXFIFOSIZE - 1)] = data;
    /*Incerment itr*/
    tx_put_itr++;
    return(TXSUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Well having read thoughtfully through code, I do not understand what it does. Could someone help me decipher it?

Comment: Where do you get this code? Can we see a full file, hopefully with a context it is in?

Comment: I know what the ~ and & does ;) the function is meant to put the data into FIFO. I don't get How the conditions works if((tx_put_itr - tx_get_itr) & ~(TXFIFOSIZE-1)) and [tx_put_itr & (TXFIFOSIZE - 1)]

Comment: The code is meant to put data into FIFO queue. The functon is to put data into FIFO

Comment: @SupportUkraine your logic is wrong in terms of simple ariphmetics. `tx_put_itr` is less then `FIFOSIZE`. No matter the difference, the result can not be larger equal then `FIFOSIZE`.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I notice that the increment goes **after** the check. NVM the above comment.

Comment: @SupportUkraine It may be useful for someone deciphering the code. To put less head around a problem.

Comment: @SupportUkraine ...and your logic is still wrong in terms of ariphmetics. `tx_put_itr` can be as much as `FIFOSIZE`. No difference can be larger. So operator `>=` is wrong here.

Comment: @KamilCuk I suggest that they are not. The `C` has a common integer conversion rules and rules for `unsigned` arithmetic. So the result **should** be basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

What the code does, is an obfuscated way to replace a more human readable code.

As a commenter wrote before me, the `TX_FIFO[tx_put_itr & (TXFIFOSIZE - 1)] = data;` loops the output. Also as it was mentioned in comments, the code is meant to have size being power of two.

I do not know why it is done so, for me `TX_FIFO[tx_put_itr % TXFIFOSIZE] = data` does the same, but more readable. Also, a person expects predicate checks to be before data access. At least it is my nature.

The `(w - r) &~ size` part is a way to check for **(1)**`w < r` and, **(2)** as an edge case, `w` being equal to `FIFOSIZE` and `r` being zero. Semantically it should have meant, that "if the write pointer points to boundary, and read pointer points to start of a buffer, we suggest that, for our data structure, next write could be an overflow."

Let us see some code, numbers and their binary representation.

```
let s = 8 - 1, in binary is 00000111 and negated is 11111000.
let w = 0, let r = 1.
now in binary w = 00000000, r = 00000001.
w - r = 11111111, logical and that with ~(8 - 1) and get some value, other then zero.
```

Continuing the logic for the `w < r` case, we get that any negative integer will produce some bits in the above. So this definitely gives `true` for the OP `if` code.

Now the `w = r` case can not commit bits to the boolean test.

And last case,

```
let s = 8,
let w = 8
let r = 0

  w - r      = 00001000
~(8 - 1)     = 11111000
(w - r) &~ 7 = 00001000
```

All other cases where `w > r` give zero.

**Update**

To my great grief, the **@UkropUkraine** had deleted all comments and his answer. There were some discussion there about the fact, that one can use `(w - r) >= mask` in place of `(w - r) & mask`.

Here I present a code, and an explanation that it is not an optimization, or just syntax, or whatever came to mind to the person who wrote the OP code. It is intended code. And it fails to do its purpose: to run as a FIFO or circular queue, or whatever that part of code was meant to do.

First, take an example of usage. The part where **Ukrop** user had difficulties. The `w` pointer can be less than `r` pointer. And the result of `w - r` will be negative.

The common usage is to add a byte to the buffer and wrap write pointer as soon as it reaches the end. Imagine situation where `w` pointer already wrapped.

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main()
{
 unsigned char w = 0, r = 1;
 int r;
 
 r = (a - b) & 0xffffffff;
 
 printf("%d\n", r);

 return 0;
}
```

> -1

I do not know what is a common boolean result type with micro controllers. For a common `x86` `C` machine, it is `int`. So I expect the `if((w - r) &~ size)` to be converted to an `int`. And the result is negative. **You can not** just write the above with `>=`, '>', or `==` as it was stated by the comments and the other answer here.

More than that, the code **fails** its semantics. It is meant to be a FIFO, or something, I do not know. But in the above situation, the read pointer still has some sensible data to read. And it can be done, because the write pointer, even if it is wrapped, does not overwrite the read portion of a buffer, **yet**. But the code returns `BUFFULL`.

I thought about read/write being different directions, but it does not change anything. The code OP gave, fails to do what one would expect.

Maybe I do miss some insight here, as **Ukrop** user, and OP, point me to the fact that they know code semantics. The OP just did not get a `~` and `&` usage. Well, this is an answer, the `~&` is used to test for a negative value and for the edge cases.

Comment: @SupportUkraine You did wrote that w = 9 will get clamped, did you?

Comment: @SupportUkraine "that the result isn't false.." - as it should, semantically. As written in my answer about the edge case.

Comment: `I do not know why it is done so` `an obfuscated way to replace a more human-readable code` A human-readable code is often replaced by obfuscated code in speed critical paths for optimization purposes. Like here - potentially a non-optimizing compiler will not replace `%` for `&` operation, and calculating `%` is a loop and inefficient, whereas `&` is mostly one instruction.

Answer (score -1):

The two operators:

`&` is a bitwise and operator

`~` is a bitwise complement operator

Now for the posted code it's important to notice that `TXFIFOSIZE` must have a value which is a power of 2, i.e. values like 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...

When that is true, the code:

```
TX_FIFO[tx_put_itr & (TXFIFOSIZE - 1)] = data;
```

is equivalent to:

```
TX_FIFO[tx_put_itr % TXFIFOSIZE] = data;
```

Notice that `tx_put_itr` is being incremented in such a way that it will take value higher than TXFIFOSIZE. So in order to get a valid array index the code must find the remainder of `tx_put_itr` with respect to TXFIFOSIZE.

So how does work? Why are the above lines equivalent?

Let's take a value as example.

```
Assume TXFIFOSIZE is 8 (2 to the power of 3)
So TXFIFOSIZE-1 is 7
7 is bitwise 00....00111
And when you do:
SOME_NUMBER & 00....00111
You keep the 3 least significant bits of SOME_NUMBER
And that is exactly the remainder of when diving by 8
```

So let's look at

```
if((tx_put_itr - tx_get_itr) & ~(TXFIFOSIZE-1))
```

It is equivalent to

```
if((tx_put_itr - tx_get_itr) >= TXFIFOSIZE)
```

So it checks for "FIFO full"

Again using an example it works like this:

```
Assume TXFIFOSIZE is 8 (2 to the power of 3)
So TXFIFOSIZE-1 is 7
7 is bitwise 00....00111
~7 is bitwise 11....11000
And when you do:
SOME_NUMBER & 11....11000
You clear the 3 least significant bits of SOME_NUMBER and keep the rest unchanged
So if the result is non-zero it means that the difference between 
tx_put_itr and tx_get_itr is 8 (or more).
```

Comment: What about a negative result?

Comment: So what? I asked about a negative result, not about index counters. And they are not counters, they called pointers, or just indices.

Comment: The buffer gets `10` data bytes being the size of `8`. The write pointer wraps around and becomes less then read pointer. Negative result from integer promotion in `C` language. You get you `>=` logic back.

Comment: What I say is that if you limit value to be less then `size`, and other value also clamped to `size`, the difference of the two values can not be larger then `size`. Why to check for `>=` in the case?